# Load wordpress from another domain inside angular 4 project?

Tags: angular, wordpress

I have siteone.com on wordpress for blog. I have sitetwo.com running Angular 4 web app.
What I am trying to figure out is that sitetwo.com/blog should load siteone.com inside it instead of redirection.

There's WP API but I need a way to achieve that with minimum effort.

Comment: You can use an iFrame to load a site into another site. Just be sure to setup the server option to allow the cross-origin requests.

Comment: I ended up creating a sub directory and migrated the project inside that directory !